# Why do most systemd examples contain WantedBy=multi-user.target?

Tags: systemd

I have read [what is multi-user.target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404667/systemd-service-what-is-multi-user-target/404671) and the [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html), which states that the multi-user.target is a special target. Further, a lot of the [systemd examples](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Examples) contain that line.

1. Why do so many example services contain that line?
2. What would happen if they did not contain WantedBy=multi-user.target?
3. Could you give me an example of when it would actually be advisable to not include that line in a service file definition?
4. Along the same lines, when is it a good idea to keep that line in?

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/591290/118399

Answer (score 190, accepted):

1.) `multi-user.target` is basically the closest equivalent of classic SysVinit runlevel 3 that `systemd` has. When a `systemd` system boots up, `systemd` is trying to make the system state match the state specified by `default.target` - which is usually an alias for either `graphical.target` or `multi-user.target`.

`multi-user.target` normally defines a system state where all network services are started up and the system will accept logins, but a local GUI is not started. This is the typical default system state for server systems, which might be rack-mounted headless systems in a remote server room.

`graphical.target` is another possible alias for `default.target`. Normally it's defined as a superset of the `multi-user.target`: it includes everything the `multi-user.target` does, plus the activation of a local GUI login. So kind of like runlevel 5 in classic SysVinit.

The line `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in a service is essentially the same as specifying "this service should start in runlevels 3, 4 and 5" in SysVinit systems: it tells `systemd` that this service should be started as part of normal system start-up, whether or not a local GUI is active.

However, `WantedBy` is separate from the enabled/disabled state: so in another sense, it's sort of a "preset": it determines under what conditions the automatic start may happen, but only when the service is enabled in the first place.

2.) if you omit the `WantedBy=multi-user.target` line and no other enabled service includes a `Requires=your.service` or `Wants=your.service` in its service definition, your service will not be started automatically.

`systemd` works on dependencies, and at boot time, if nothing `Requires` or `Wants` your service, it won't be started even if the service is enabled.

Sure, you could edit your `default.target` to add or delete `Requires` or `Wants` lines for any services you want started at boot time - but so that you can just drop a new service file into the system and have it work by default (which makes things very easy for software package managers), `systemd` has the `WantedBy` and `RequiredBy` keywords which can be used to insert `Wants` and `Requires`-type dependencies (respectively) from "the other end".

3.) You should omit the line if you *don't* want the service to be ever started automatically at boot time, *or* this service is a part of a chain of dependencies you've defined explicitly.

For example, you might be refactoring server application A and for some reason or another decide to split some optional functionality off it into a separate service B, to allow the user the choice of not installing it if it isn't needed. You could then make service B a separate `service-B.rpm`, and define `B.service` with `WantedBy=A.service` to make `systemd` start up service B automatically whenever service A is started - but only when `service-B.rpm` is actually installed.

Note that a `Wants` or `WantedBy` only says that the system should startup one service whenever another service or target is also started, but it specifies nothing at all about the startup/shutdown order. If you need service B to be already running when service A starts up, you'd need to add `Before=A.service` in the `B.service` file to explicitly specify the start-up order dependency.

4.) Anytime you *do* want the service to have the capability of being started automatically at boot time, and there are no other dependencies already defined.

Comment: Cool! lots of good info here. "Note that a Wants or WantedBy only says that the system should startup one service whenever another service *[edit:] or target* is also started, but it specifies nothing at all about the startup/shutdown order." - unfortunately the edit is not quite right, it is more complicated. `man systemd.target` says when you are wanted by a *target*, you are also automatically ordered before the target. This explains why the logs show `graphical.target` is only "started" after all the services are. Unless the wanted unit (or the target?) has `DefaultDependencies=no`.

Comment: Does this apply for `Type=oneshot` services which are intended to be triggered by something else (like a notification service)? Would the oneshot be run also for each boot?

Comment: @nealmcb If you want the oneshot be triggered for each boot, then you'd put in the `[Install] Wanted-By=<multi-user|graphical|whatever>.target`; but if you want it to **only** be triggered by your "something else", then you'd omit it.

Answer (score 17):

If you remove `WantedBy=multi-user.target`, then `systemctl enable your-example-here` will (noisily) fail to do anything.

### graphical.target

If you install pure systemd from the source, the "default target" that it boots to is `graphical.target`.

Starting `graphical.target` starts `multi-user.target`, plus whatever unit(s) are required to provide a graphical user interface.  This extra complexity was arranged in an attempt to emulate legacy "runlevels".

You *really* should ignore / gloss over the "runlevel" emulation; it does not work correctly anyway.  Sorry!  I guess the reason for emphasizing "graphical" v.s. "multi-user" historically is that graphics software is 1) not as robust and mature as the rest of the system and 2) requires a lot of resources.

Typically only a few units are specific to `graphical.target`.  There is a single service for the GUI itself like `gdm.target`.  There are a few support services that are *mostly* used by the GUI here as well.

Edit: Googling suggests that if you don't have a GUI installed, but the "default target" has been left as `graphical.target`, then systemd might log a warning. "Cannot add dependency job for unit display-manager.service, ignoring: Unit display-manager.service failed to load: No such file or directory."  We want to avoid littering our logs with unnecessary warnings.  So if you did not install a GUI, it is good to use `systemctl set-default multi-user`.  Although the install system for your OS might have taken care of this for you already.  Other than that, I am strongly in favour of apathy in this matter :-).

### sysinit.target

Some services and other types of units are "involved in early boot".  They are defined to start `Before=sysinit.target` - either directly or indirectly.  Most services are only started `After=sysinit.target` - this is automatically the case, unless the service sets `DefaultDependencies=no`.

### multi-user.target

Most example services do not fall under either of the above categories, therefore we attach them to `multi-user.target`.  This includes most network services (e.g. a web server), which are the archetypal system service.

### dynamically activated services

Another possibility you might see, is a service unit that is *not* started automatically at boot.  So it would not need `WantedBy=multi-user.target`.  The service can instead be triggered or "activated" by something else.

One example of this is a dbus activated service.  Dbus can be configured to start your service on-demand, when a dbus call is made to the service.

For network services, you can use socket-activated services.  This might be easier to find details about, because all the configuration is in systemd units.  For example `sshd.socket` or `ssh.socket` is typically available to activate `ssh@.service` or `sshd@.service`.  Although, I think it is more common to start the sshd service at boot time.

---

As always, the above simplifies and omits details which did not seem to be required.

Answer (score 5):

The `multi-user.target` is a semantic name, that is, it is associated with a meaning. Allow me to demonstrate the concept with a counterexample. I will make the argument that the decision to use `multi-user.target` depends on the context.

If you were to create a systemd *user unit* configuration rather than a *system unit* configuration, you might naively follow the conventions of the systemd system units and use `multi-user.target`<sup>1</sup>.

## Explanation by Counter-Example

Consider the file `/home/jonathan/.config/systemd/user/coolstuff.service`

This user will only by used with respect to user `jonathan`, therefore it hardly makes sense to call my target "multi-user.target".

```
[Unit]
Description=Does some cool stuff.

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/echo "Cool stuff" >> %h/coolstuff.txt'

[Install]
WantedBy=user.target
```

Note how I opted to use `WantedBy=`**user.target**. This is because the scope of this context is my user account, therefore I opted to use my own semantic conventions. In other words, multiple users will not be affected by this unit. On the system level however, it makes more sense to follow standardized conventions because of the parallel startup sequence. During startup, many procedures converge on multiple targets. The `multi-user.target` is semantically associated with the idea of "read for user engagement / interaction with the system" (without a windowing system as telcoM mentioned), therefore it is a safe bet for most system unit files.

**Footnotes**

1. Although it would not make sense from within this context, it would still work.

Comment: I doubt it would work. The expectation here is that the service would not be started because the multi-user.target is simply not known to a systemd user unit configuration. Creating a systemd user unit configuration rather than a system unit configuration implies running a `systemd --user` instance which has its own targets. You'd want to use the `default.target` then.

Comment: Well @duise, it is not a question of whether it would work. It *will* work provided you have a target called `user.target`. As mentioned explicitly, ”I opted to use my own semantic conventions.“ All targets are semantic conventions that serve as latches. You can list *your* targets using `systemctl list-units —user —type=target`. Creating targets is beyond the scope of this question.