# Best practice for Wants= vs WantedBy= in Systemd Unit Files

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

As far as I can tell from the documentation of [systemd](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.1.en.html), `Wants=` and `WantedBy=` perform the same function, except that the former is put in the dependent unit file and vice-versa.  (That, and `WantedBy=` creates the `unit.type.wants` directory and populates it with symlinks.)

From [DigitalOcean: Understanding Systemd Units and Unit Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files#anatomy-of-a-unit-file):

> The `WantedBy=` directive... allows you to specify a dependency relationship in a similar way to the `Wants=` directive does in the `[Unit]` section. The difference is that this directive is included in the ancillary unit allowing the primary unit listed to remain relatively clean.

Is it really just about keeping a unit file "clean"?  What is the best practice for using these two directives?  That is, if service alpha "wants" service beta, when should I use `Wants=beta.service` in `alpha.service` and when should I prefer `WantedBy=alpha.service` in the `beta.service`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Functionally

`Wants` is in the `Unit` section and `WantedBy` is in the `Install`.

The init process `systemd` does not process/use the `Install` section at all. Instead, a symlink must be created in `multi-user.target.wants`. Usually, that's done by the utility `systemctl` which does read the `Install` section.

In summary, *`WantedBy` is affected by `systemctl enable`/`systemctl disable`.*

### Logically

Consider which of the services should "know" or be "aware" of the other. For example, a common use of `WantedBy`:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Alternatively, that could be in multi-user.target:

```
[Unit]
Wants=nginx.service
```

But that second way doesn't make sense. Logically, nginx.service knows about the system-defined multi-user.target, not the other way around.

So in your example, if alpha's author is aware of beta, then alpha `Wants` beta. If beta's author is aware of alpha then beta is `WantedBy` alpha.

To help you decide, you may consider which service can be installed (say, from a package manager) without the other being present.

#### Config directories

As another tool in your box, know that systemd files can also be extended with config directories: /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/extension.conf

This allows you to add dependencies where neither service is originally authored to know about the other. I often use this with mounts, where (for example) neither nginx nor the mount need explicit knowledge of the other, but I as the system adminstrator understand the dependency. So I create `nginx.service.d/mymount.conf` with `Wants=mnt-my.mount`.

Comment: Super helpful.  I have an issue where nginx is failing on boot because the vpn interface it binds to hasn't started yet.  Based on the last section, it sounds like `Wants` is best fix for this init race condition.

Comment: Also, if WantedBy is more useful for runtime with systemctl, will it try to start the dependent service automatically when you systemctl start alpha?

Comment: @Keith, yes WantedBy will start prerequisite service first. It will not however, prevent the other service from starting should the prerequisite fail. (For a stronger dependency, see RequiredBy.)

Answer (score 2):

These are not functionally identical.  The `Wants=` setting (and the symbolic link files) is the dependency.  The `WantedBy=` setting controls the creation/destruction of such a dependency when a service is enabled/disabled.

So there's no *best* practice.  There's *correct* practice.  Only one of the two has the correct functionality for any given situation.  Either one intends to have a persistent dependency that always exists, or one intends to have a transient dependency that can be turned on and off with `enable`/`disable`.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand.  Could you give examples of when each would be correct?

Comment: I second Keith's question: the answer does not really help understand the distinction and examples would make a big difference.