# Bind smartd to user session

Tags: systemd, notify-send, smartmontools

I want to see smartd notifications in DE (Gnome3). So I've configured smartd to execute custom script that uses notify-send to notify all logged users:

**smartd.conf**:

```
/dev/sda -m root -M test -M exec /etc/smartmontools/smartd_warning.d/notify -a -n standby,10,q
```

**smartd_warning.d/notify**:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

IFS=$'\n'
for LINE in `w -hs`
do
    USER=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'`
    USER_ID=`id -u $USER`
    DISP_ID=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $8}'`
    sudo -u $USER DISPLAY=$DISP_ID DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$USER_ID/bus notify-send "S.M.A.R.T Error ($SMARTD_FAILTYPE)" "$SMARTD_MESSAGE" --icon=dialog-warning
done
```

it works correctly only if I restart `smartd` when I logged into system. Obviously it can't work on boot, because `smartd` starts before any user logged into system.

```
[Unit]
Description=Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon
Documentation=man:smartd(8) man:smartd.conf(5)

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/smartmontools
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smartd -n $smartd_opts
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
StandardOutput=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can bind smartd service to user session to see those notifications?

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing your `WantedBy` to `graphical.target` or `default.target` according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506347/why-do-most-systemd-examples-contain-wantedby-multi-user-target).

 Short explanation; `multi-user.target` means the system is up but it does not mean a user is logged on, `graphical.target` implies a local user login, and `default.target` is a common alias for `graphical.target` but might be aliased to other values as well.

Also, if you want to simply ensure you are not missing any notifications you could `echo` the same data you are sending via notify-send to a file as well. Which should be something like:

`echo "S.M.A.R.T Error ($SMARTD_FAILTYPE)" "$SMARTD_MESSAGE" >> /"YourPathHere"/smartd.log`

(Be sure to use a path that your script can write to though)

Comment: I"ve tried and it's not working. The reason is that you can send a message via DBus to any user only when he's actually logged into system (see `w -hs` command). There's no any queue. Your second suggestion seems reasonable, I've thought about that too, but I'd like to see notification, and to do so I'd have to parse and clear such log manually. In that case keeping each message as separate file looks more simple to manage (`../smartlog/*.msg`). Right... it looks like I reinvent the email.