# Systemd service does not start (WantedBy=multi-user.target)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, boot, services, systemd-unit

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3

```bsh
$ \cat /home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/Festival.service
[Unit]
Description=Festival Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/festival --server
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=FestivalService

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Description

I did `systemctl --user enable Festival.service`, rebooted my system. But the festival server does not start. Only  when I do manually `systemctl --user start Festival.service`, it starts.

### Issue

Could you please tell me, why user service does not work with `multi-user.target`, which is suppose to work on every boot?

### Reference

- [Why do most systemd examples contain WantedBy=multi-user.target? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506347/why-do-most-systemd-examples-contain-wantedby-multi-user-target)

Comment: What was the output of `systemctl --user enable Festival.service`? It should tell you something about the symlinks created.

Comment: @TNW `Created symlink /home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/multi-user.target.wants/Festival.service → /home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/Festival.service.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`multi-user.target` is appropriate for the system-bus, but you are using `--user` which works with the user-bus.  The user-bus does not typically have `multi-user.target`

```
stew ~ $ sudo systemctl status multi-user.target
● multi-user.target - Multi-User System
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target; static)
     Active: active since Fri 2021-08-27 10:09:41 CEST; 5h 19min ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Aug 27 10:09:41 stewbian systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.


stew ~ $ systemctl --user status multi-user.target
Unit multi-user.target could not be found.
```

The solution is to either use the system bus (which will start the service on boot), or use the user bus (which will start when the user logs in).

If you choose to stick with the user bus then change `multi-user.target` to `default.target` (which is the main user target).

If you choose to switch to the system bus, then you can still run the service as your user with `User=` in the `[Service]` section.

See [`man systemd.special`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html) for info about these targets.

Comment: Thanks I will accept after testing it. Also, if we are trying to start an application that requires GUI such as Firefox from user service,  can we use default.target?

Comment: For a GUI app, the user-bus is certainly the way to go. [`graphical-session.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#graphical-session.target) or [`xdg-desktop-autostart.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#xdg-desktop-autostart.target) are the design for starting GUI applications, but in reality these are not implemented by all desktop environments yet.  Try these first for `firefox`.  If these are not implemented on your machine, then `default.target` is your answer (though this may also run if you login via ssh)

Comment: Some people may suggest `graphical.target` on the system bus, but the problem with this is you need to manually set the `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` environment variables in your service, you need to set `User=` and it will try to start when reaching the display manager login screen instead of when the desktop environment is started.

Comment: I enabled using `graphical-seesion.target`. I see that this got created `/home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/graphical-session.target.wants/Browser.service`. Also, I saw that the folder `/usr/lib/systemd/user/graphical-session.target.wants
` exists. So, `graphical-session.target.wants` can exists in 2 locations, right?

Comment: When enabling a unit, systemd creates a symbolic link in `*.wants/` to your unit.  When starting `graphical-session.target`, systemd check `graphical-session.target.wants/` to set the `Wants=` relationship. Then raises any units with a link in that directory.

Comment: Could you please also look at [bash - Systemd user service fails after reboot but works manually properly - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667251/systemd-user-service-fails-after-reboot-but-works-manually-properly)