# Systemd user service fails after reboot but works manually properly

Tags: bash, scripting, systemd, services, reboot

- Note: `~/opt/bin/MemoryDiagnostics` is a bash script and is executable.

```
$ cat MemoryDiagnostics.service

[Unit]
Description=MemoryDiagnostics Service

[Service]
ExecStart="%h/opt/bin/MemoryDiagnostics"
SyslogIdentifier=MemoryDiagnosticsService

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```bsh
$ systemctl --user enable MemoryDiagnostics.service 
Created symlink /home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/MemoryDiagnostics.service → /home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/MemoryDiagnostics.service.
```

Then Reboot. Observation: Service fails after reboot

```bsh
$ systemctl --user status MemoryDiagnostics.service 
● MemoryDiagnostics.service - MemoryDiagnostics Service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/MemoryDiagnostics.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-09-02 02:34:32 CEST; 11min ago
    Process: 1549 ExecStart=/home/nikhil/opt/bin/MemoryDiagnostics (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1549 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 02 02:34:29 X550JX systemd[1147]: Started MemoryDiagnostics Service.
Sep 02 02:34:32 X550JX systemd[1147]: MemoryDiagnostics.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 02 02:34:32 X550JX systemd[1147]: MemoryDiagnostics.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

- Service starts when done manually:

```bsh
$ systemctl --user start MemoryDiagnostics.service 
$ systemctl --user status MemoryDiagnostics.service 
● MemoryDiagnostics.service - MemoryDiagnostics Service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/MemoryDiagnostics.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-09-02 02:48:13 CEST; 4s ago
   Main PID: 9941 (bash)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/MemoryDiagnostics.service
             ├─9941 bash /home/nikhil/opt/bin/MemoryDiagnostics
             └─9970 sleep 121

Sep 02 02:48:13 X550JX systemd[1147]: Started MemoryDiagnostics Service.
```

---

Why does the shell script fails after reboot, but works perfectly fine when started manually?

Answer (score 0):

`~/opt/bin/MemoryDiagnostics` is exiting with exit code 1.  That means the failure is internal to the application.  It's disappointing that `MemoryDiagnostics` doesn't log more info to stderr so that we can help give it what it needs.  But we can make some guesses:

- If `MemoryDiagnostics` launches a GUI, then change `WantedBy=default.target` to `WantedBy=graphical-session.target`.
- If `MemoryDiagnistics` depends on other resources, we can add `After=` to our `[Unit]` section to be sure the dependency is ready.  Some dependencies which may be relevant could be:

  - `After=bluetooth.target` if you are also checking (or failing to check) bluetooth.
  - `After=default.target` if you need other services that are raised by `default.target`
  - Any other custom units (perhaps mounts or services) that you need ready before running this.

---

If you are unable to figure out which dependency needs to be ready, (or perhaps that dependency takes time to start, but doesn't use inotify) then you can always add `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5` to add an artificial 5s delay to starting.

This method is easier to configure, but will either add unnecessary delay or will risk starting too early.

---

If you do like the `ExecStartPre=sleep` method, and you don't necessarily need this to run immediately, just often.  Then you can also consider using a `*.timer` to start your unit.  In that case, I'd delete the `[Install]` section from yor service, and instead create the following timer:

```
# ~/.config/systemd/user/MemoryDiagnostics.timer
[Unit]
Description=MemoryDiagnostics Timer

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then `systemctl --user enable MemoryDiagnostics.timer` and let it handle executing the service.

This is effectively equivalent to the `ExecStart=sleep` solution above, but also gives you extra power to add/change things like:

- `OnCalendar=` which will run your diagnostics on a schedule
- `RandomizedDelaySec=` which will apply a random offset to the firing of the service to avoid lots of services firing at the same time.